# AutomationPeer, update UIA tree when children get removed

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, automationpeer

*(Beginner with UI Automation and WPF here, so perhaps I'm doing things very wrong.)*

We have a custom control that displays items to be interactively viewed or edited. In adding UI Automation support I now used an appropriate implementation of `OnCreateAutomationPeer` and implemented an `AutomationPeer` specific for that control. Things seem to be working fine for the most part. I can see our children in the UIA tree and when I add children they appear there.

From what I've seen now in the .NET Source is that thr tree changes work automagically because each `UpdateLayout` from within the bowels of WPF causes the respective `AutomationPeer`s to refresh their subtree. So those things work fine out of the box.

However, when removing an item my `AutomationPeer`'s `GetChildrenCore` is not called, apparently because WPF doesn't really need to update anything when a `Visual` is removed from its tree. This leads to the UIA tree containing elements that are no longer there.

Now I wonder though, how this is supposed to work in general. I saw that some controls notify their `AutomationPeer`s directly when something changes. This might be a route. Or should our custom control do something different so that layout happens even when something is removed?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue with an ItemsControl - I update the contents dynamically and it does not refresh the children for use with automation.

In my user control I added code that was triggered on a viewmodel event, which then called ResetChildrenCache() on the automation peer.
My Code looks like this:

```
viewModel.DisplayedFaults.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    automationPeer = UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(AutomationUiItemsControl);
    if (automationPeer != null)
    {
        automationPeer.ResetChildrenCache();
    }
};
```

It was based on this article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/636a37a6-d766-46f8-bafb-d4d9a7816345/wpf-ui-automation-on-a-treeview?forum=windowsaccessibilityandautomation

Another Useful link I found related to this kind of thing is:
[Some controls on a page are not visible for MS UI Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793298/some-controls-on-a-page-are-not-visible-for-ms-ui-automation)

Comment: In your code, if the FromElement() returns non-null, you reset the cache.  But why on non-null?  PS: The first link has expired and is not on the wayback machine.  Have you saved the original link by any chance?  Thank you.